# Python KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, upnp

I Have a Keyerror with this python code

```
service = self.get_cd_service()
browse_response = service.Browse(ObjectID=str(object_id),
                                 BrowseFlag=browse_flag,
                                 Filter=filter,
                                 StartingIndex=starting_index,
                                 RequestedCount=requested_count,
                                 SortCriteria=sort_criteria)
elt = Element.from_string(browse_response['Result'])
browse_response['Result'] = elt.get_items()
return browse_response
```

And the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CommandlLineControlPointAv.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "CommandlLineControlPointAv.py", line 89, in main
    cmdline.run()
  File "CommandlLineControlPointAv.py", line 68, in run
    self.cmd_browse(c.split(' ')[1])
  File "CommandlLineControlPointAv.py", line 48, in cmd_browse
    result = self.browse(id, 'BrowseDirectChildren', '*', 0, 10)['Result']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/brisa/upnp/control_point/control_point_av.py", line 136, in browse
    elt = Element.from_string(browse_response['Result'])
KeyError: 'Result'
```

Thx for your help/
Best regards.

Rem

Comment: `service.Browse()` may be not returns dict.

Comment: What does browse response look like? Is the key error on the line where you set elt, or the line after?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You get a `TypeError` if the object is not subscriptable, not a `KeyError`.

Comment: @chepner Yes,  because `Lists` and `tuples` can't be indexed by string. Am I correct

Comment: If you try to give a list or tuple a string index, you also get a `TypeError`, not a `KeyError`. `browse_response` appears to be a `dict`, just one without a "Result" key.

Answer (score 3):

browse_response does not have a key `Result` check what browse_reponse contains

You could drop in a debugger right after `service.Browse` call
`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

you could log the `broser_response` object through python [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)